# Font size is too small

Tags: fonts, gui, 21.10

I have problem that text size of lots of application are to small as Chrome, VsCode, etc. unlike system font(tweak settings).

[VsCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUKbU.png)
As you see file names and setting texts are too small unlike output box.

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBj3A.png)
Address bar text and other text

[Tweak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7EE5.png)
text size of tweak interface is good but you can see chrome address bar is too smaller than this.

Properties: OS: Ubuntu 21.10, GPU: Nvida GTX 1660, CPU: Core i7 10th gen.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to lower the display resolution generally (in Settings -> Displays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the "Scaling factor" in "Tweaks", "Fonts" tab a little, up to 1.1 or 1.2. This will increase all fonts and likely, you will find a value there that is pleasing.

Comment: But the other texts will be big.

Comment: Play with the settings.